# Plots Frame (including axes) blackened in Qtconsole

Tags: matplotlib, pandas, plot, ipython, qtconsole

When I launch qtconsole with the --colors=linux option and plot something the frame of the plot is blackened so I cannot see the axes because the qtconsole background is also black.

I used to launch this before without problem but have this problem after a recent update of pandas. I am not sure about what changed but I thought there might be a setting I can change to fix this anyway without worrying about what the update modified that broke this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the axes are set to transparent by default (this was not happening before).

The following plots as desired, showing the white axes on black background:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_alpha(1)
temp = pd.Series(range(100))
temp.plot()
```

I would also like to set this behavior as the default one. I have not been able to do that yet. This seemed like a good lead,

http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

but I could not find an option for exactly that yet.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.